# Java keypressed event not firing

Tags: java, applet, awt, keylistener, awtrobot

During writing this code I realized if making into a jar there would have to be a graceful way to close the program. I have chosen to use the key 'F1'. I've researched a few articles online and found that the way I'm trying to handle it should be a viable approach, but the program doesn't even seem to fire the event method. The system.out.println never displays.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;


public class MouseMove extends Applet implements KeyListener{

public static Random randomGenerator = new Random();
public static int code;

public void init(){
    addKeyListener(this);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt){
    code = evt.getKeyCode();
    System.out.println("Key: "+KeyEvent.getKeyText(code));

    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_F1){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){   
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

        Robot robot = new Robot();          

        while(true){

            robot.mouseMove((int)(Math.random()*1366), (int)(Math.random()*768));
            robot.delay(5000);
            robot.mouseWheel((int)(Math.random()*786));
            robot.delay(5000);
        }
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//main

}//class
```

Comment: On my side your program is working nicely, You need to click on your applet once, that System.out.println(); code is showing which key is being pressed. I couldn't find any issue with this.

Comment: On my end the println() never fires. and the program continues to execute without end. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `KeyListener` works only if `Component` has `Focus` in the Window.
2. You have to create a `visible` Container.
3. `setFocusable()` for Component
4. Better would be use Swing `JComponent`.
5. Use `JFrame` instead of `JApplet`.

Comment: I was looking to avoid any visible objects. I wanted the program to remain invisible and only stop execution upon hitting the F1 key. Will my approach not work?

Comment: then you play with first anti-virus instaled on concrete PC

Answer (score 1):

You never make an instance of `MouseMove`. Your main method just makes the robot and starts looping. If the object doesn't exists, one of it's methods can never be called.

Comment: Still learning, was thinking the init() was taking care of it. Anything other than MouseMove move = new MouseMove(); move.init()needed in main? Because it still isn't responding, it crashes IDE, but doesn't actually stop execution. Is there a better way to gracefully stop execution?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use System.exit() when you working with applets. Take a look at [Java Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) (tutorial). You need to create .htm document and add `<applet>` tag to run an applet. You may use `AppletViewer` tool or web-browser to launch that htm document.

file.htm

```
<applet code="MouseMove" width="200" height="200"></applet>
```

start Appletviewer tool from command-line or open .htm in web-browser.

```
>appletviewer file.htm
```